# solve for $y$ in $e^{xy}+x^2+y-1.2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I cant figure out how to make $y$ the subject in this equation: 
>   $$e^{xy}+x^2+y-1.2=0$$

I did these steps,

$$\begin{align}&y=1.2-x^2-e^{xy}\\
&\ln(y)=\ln(1.2)-\ln(x^2)-\ln(e^{xy})\\
&\ln(y)=\ln(1.2)-\ln(x^2)-xy\\
&\ln(y)+xy=\ln\frac{1.2}{x^2}\end{align}$$

ahead of this I am lost and would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: This function is not linear! In other words, the log of a sum (ie, the right hand side) is NOT the sum of the logs.

Comment: that means the second step should be $ln(y)=ln(1.2-x^2-e^{xy})$? How do i proceed ahead of this though? There should be another way to handle this since it doesnt bring me any nearer to solve for y

Comment: That is what the seconds step *would* be. I agree that it doesn't seem to move you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=1.2$, rearrange a little and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{-xy} (a-x^2-y)=1.
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply by $xe^{ax-x^3}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (\color{red}{ax-x^3-xy})e^{\color{red}{ax-x^3-xy}}=xe^{ax-x^3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now recall the Lambert $W$ function is defined by $\color{red}we^{\color{red}w}=z$ gives $w=W(z)$. So we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
ax-x^3-xy =W(xe^{ax-x^3}) \\
y=\frac{ax-x^3-W(xe^{ax-x^3})}{x}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

This equation has no solutions in terms of elementary functions. Mathematica returns

$$y=\frac{-5 W\left(e^{-x \left(x^2-\frac{6}{5}\right)} x\right)-5 x^3+6 x}{5 x}$$

where $W$ denotes the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Im sorry you started with the wrong equation, which was primarily my fault since I've used math jax for the first time. I've edited the equation since to the reflect the correct one.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 The question was edited after I posted this answer.

Comment: thankyou so much for the answer. Could you please provide the steps leading up to the lambert function too?

Comment: @BlitzMee I cannot. This is not an equation one can solve by hand.